# How to write GROUP BY SQL query in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Help me in writing GROUP_BY condition in ruby. I have to migrate PHP-project to Ruby now, and faced with this problem. Do not judge strictly, I'm new in Ruby.

This is query in php:

```
$get_details_email = db_query("Select secret_key,trustee_status,email_id from trustees where request_by='email' AND user_id='$user_id' group by email_id");
```

How to group the query below on email_id?

```
get_details_email = Trustee.select(:secret_key, :trustee_status, :email_id).where(:request_by => 'email', :user_id => user_id)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
get_details_email = Trustee.select(:secret_key, :trustee_status, :email_id).where(:request_by => 'email', :user_id => user_id).group(:email_id)
```